# Excluding records from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a table which I am trying to return only records of rendition_type Interactive and no other associated rendition_type. If a records has more than one rendition_type, I need to exclude it from the list.

```
DOC_ID    RENDITION_ID    RENDITION_TYPE
001       001             Interactive
001       002             Web PDF
002       003             Interactive
003       004             Interactive
003       005             Print PDF
004       006             Interactive
005       007             Interactive
005       008             Web PDF
```

I'm looking for a query that will return only rows where document_ID has Rendition_type type of only 1 and that type is Interactive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to give you what you want.

```
--demo setup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DocumentTable;
go
CREATE TABLE DocumentTable
    (DOC_ID int, RENDITION_ID int, RENDITION_TYPE varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO DocumentTable
    (DOC_ID, RENDITION_ID, RENDITION_TYPE)
VALUES
    (001, 001, 'Interactive'),
    (001, 002, 'Web PDF'),
    (002, 003, 'Interactive'),
    (003, 004, 'Interactive'),
    (003, 005, 'Print PDF'),
    (004, 006, 'Interactive'),
    (005, 007, 'Interactive'),
    (005, 008, 'Web PDF')
;

--solution
SELECT *
FROM DocumentTable a
WHERE RENDITION_TYPE = 'Interactive'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM DocumentTable
        WHERE DOC_ID = a.doc_id
            AND RENDITION_TYPE <> 'Interactive'
        )
```

---

```
| DOC_ID | RENDITION_ID | RENDITION_TYPE |
|--------|--------------|----------------|
| 2      | 3            | Interactive    |
| 4      | 6            | Interactive    |
```